# Cast 'new' and 'old' dynamically

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, casting

I have table `client` and table `client_history` to keep change history of the records.
For these purposes I have created a database UPDATE trigger which executes `log_record_changes()` procedure.

I also have other tables and their own `{table_name}_history` tables, BUT every history table thas the same structure. Structure of `client_history` table is presented below:

```
create table "client_history"
(
    id             bigserial      not null,
    client_id      bigint         not null,
    action         history_action not null default 'CREATE',
    changed_values json                    default null,
    performed_at   timestamp      not null default current_timestamp,
    performed_by   bigint         not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Taking into account everything above I have a universal trigger function which determines what chages have been made and insert `old` record to the history table. This allows me to write single function which can handle all changes from all history tables rather than create function for every single one of them.
Function code is presented below:

```
create or replace function log_record_changes() returns trigger as
$$
declare
    action_type    text;
    changed_values json;
    new_record     record;
begin
    action_type = case
                      when tg_op = 'INSERT' then 'CREATE'
                      when tg_op = 'UPDATE' then 'EDIT'
                      else ''
        end;

    if action_type = 'EDIT' and new.archived_at <> old.archived_at then
        action_type = 'ARCHIVE';
    elseif action_type = 'EDIT' and new.deleted_at <> old.deleted_at then
        action_type = 'DELETE';
    end if;

    if action_type = '' then
        raise exception 'не удалось определить тип действия по типу триггера. Тип триггера: %', tg_op;
    end if;

    changed_values = (select json_agg(json_build_object(main_source.column_name, main_source.old_value))
                      from (select column_name,
                                   row_to_json(n) -> column_name #>> '{}' AS new_value,
                                   row_to_json(o) -> column_name #>> '{}' AS old_value
                            from cast(new as client) as n,
                                 cast(old as client) as o,
                                 (select json_object_keys(row_to_json(c)) as column_name
                                  from cast(new as client) as c) as test) as main_source
                      where main_source.new_value is distinct from main_source.old_value);

    execute format('insert into %I (%I, action, changed_values, performed_by) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)',
                   tg_table_name || '_history', tg_table_name || '_id')
        using old.id, cast(action_type as history_action), changed_values, cast(
                    (select current_setting('custom.application_user_id')) as bigint);

    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The problem is that in the current implementation I specifically cast my `new` and `old` records to the `client` relation thus update of the `client` relation goes well. But if I try to update another table this procedure will fail because it is impossible to cast another table to `client`.

I want to implement some kind of dynamic casting based on the trigger parameter `tg_table_name` but I'm out of ideas how to do this.

Could you guys hepl me?

Comment: Hello @Laurenz Albe! Thank you for your reference to similar question. I understand that I need to use `hstore`. I have modified my procedure but I cant figure out how to achieve the same behaviour as my current implementation has. Could you please help me?

Comment: You would not use `hstore`, but `jsonb` these days. Writing up the required code would consume too much of my time, sorry.